# How to inialize and access the entries in Mat scalars matrix in openCV using C++ interface?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I am trying to do some basic algebraic operations on matrices. 
I would like to use the class Mat from openCV. 
I used the following simple code which wouldn't work:

```
void main()
{
  float data[2][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{7,8,9,10,11}}; 
  Mat H = Mat(2, 5, CV_8UC1, data); 
  cout << H.at<float>(0,0);
  //OR:
  cout << H;
}
```

Now I have already encountered a similar problem in loading an image by the imread function. 
I've overcomed it by starting from C and then pass to C++:

```
IplImage* Csrc = cvLoadImage("D:/picture.jpg");
Mat src(Csrc);
```

which did work. 
Could anyone help with the scalars matrices? How could I print the entries for example ?
Thank you.

Comment: How does it not work? Bear in mind that `CV_8UC1` means 8 bit unsigned integer types.

Comment: It would also help if you clarified what you mean by "wouldn't work", and provide some self-contained code that replicates the problem.

Comment: O.K. let us concentrate on the first suggestion, namely:        float data[2][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{7,8,9,10,11}};                   Mat H=Mat(2,5,CV_32FC1,data);                                       cout << H;        The error message after getting to this line is: Unhandled exception at 0x6913DE19 (msvcp100.dll) in openCV 3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem of your code is that data[2][5] is a float matrix and H is a matrix of unsined character.

Declare the matrix H as -

`Mat H=Mat(2,5,CV_32FC1,data);`

Your second problem is very simple

To read a image as a cvMat object and display it, just do -

```
Mat M = imread("/home/Pictures/image.png",1);
imshow("IMAGE",M);
waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Maybe it comes from a bad configuration, but I have seen that other users had encoutered the same problems...

Comment: what do you meant by "bad configuration " ?

Comment: I have tried for days to follow all kinds of instructions in the WEB while installing the openCV - adding including to different directories and libraries, also with the extensions ending with d (debug) and the imread just wouldn't work. Untill I saw many users had the same problem which could be solved as written (by passing from C to C++).

Comment: In that case ,before adding any more comment, install OpenCV properly in your system.

Comment: This exactely the problem, and aparently I am not the only one having it - try to google "error imread" and read about so many users that share the same problem. Believe me I tried to install it so many times in so many ways. It just wouldn't work. So I adapted the solution written above (from C to C++).

Comment: Which version of opencv you are using ? Can you give the full code you are trying to compile ?